Update flutter pub cache in bitbucket pipelines
While running build script in bitbucket pipeline it gives error
> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':paytm_allinonesdk:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> 'compileReleaseJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileReleaseKotlin' task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
  Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

As this error is resolved in local machine by changing local pub cache.
But in pipeline as it re-download pub cache while running script.
I want to know is there any type of solution for this type of error not occur in pipeline.
Any changes required in build.gradle of app or android.
# Use an official Flutter image as the base
FROM maven:3.3.9

FROM ghcr.io/cirruslabs/android-sdk:34

RUN apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install -y \
        curl \
        wget \
        git \
        iputils-ping \
        unzip \
        xz-utils && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Download and install SonarScanner CLI
RUN curl -o /tmp/sonar-scanner.zip https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-6.1.0.4477-linux-x64.zip && \
    unzip /tmp/sonar-scanner.zip -d /opt && \
    rm /tmp/sonar-scanner.zip

# Set up SonarScanner environment variables
ENV SONAR_SCANNER_HOME=/opt/sonar-scanner-6.1.0.4477-linux-x64
ENV PATH="$SONAR_SCANNER_HOME/bin:$PATH"

# Download and install Flutter SDK
RUN wget https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_3.24.0-stable.tar.xz -O /opt/flutter_3.24.0.tar.xz
RUN tar -xf /opt/flutter_3.24.0.tar.xz -C /opt/
RUN rm -f /opt/flutter_3.24.0.tar.xz

# Set up environment variables for Flutter
ENV FLUTTER_HOME=/opt/flutter
ENV PATH="$FLUTTER_HOME/bin:$PATH"

RUN git config --global --add safe.directory /opt/flutter

# Ensure Flutter dependencies are installed
RUN flutter doctor

# Set working directory for the app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the project files into the container
COPY . /app

So this is my docker image

Would you be able to post the bitbucket pipeline? There is likely an issue with the docker image you are using.

Updated question
